# Verifying GCP JWT signature manually in JS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, x509, webcrypto-api, jose

I've been able to verify a GCP ID token on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)'s web UI okay, but am struggling to replicated it in code in JS.

I've used both the `jose` and the `jsrsasign` libraries to little success.

A bit of my own code to get the basics

```
function decodeJWT(jwtString: string) {
  const jwt = jwtString.match(
    /(?<header>[^.]+)\.(?<payload>[^.]+)\.(?<signature>[^.]+)/
  ).groups;

  // For simplicity trust that the urlBase64toStr function works
  // The parsed JWT is identical to what I see on jwt.io
  jwt.header = JSON.parse(urlBase64toStr(jwt.header));
  jwt.payload = JSON.parse(urlBase64toStr(jwt.payload));

  return jwt;
}

const jwt = decodeJWT('<....JWT string here......>')

const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const byteArrays = {
    signature: encoder.encode(jwt.signature),
    body: encoder.encode(
      JSON.stringify(jwt.header) + "." + JSON.stringify(jwt.payload)
    )
};

// Google's public certs at https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
const cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n<........>'
```

Verifying with `jose` gives `false`

```
  const joseKey = await jose.importX509(cert, "RS256");
  console.log(
      await crypto.subtle.verify(
        joseKey.algorithm.name,
        joseKey,
        byteArrays.signature,
        byteArrays.body
      )
  ) 

// Note the following works

console.log(jose.jwtVerify(jwtRaw, joseKey))
```

Using `jsrsaassign` also gives `false`

```
  var c = new jsrsasign.X509();
  c.readCertPEM(cert);

  var jsRsaAssignKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    jsrsasign.KEYUTIL.getJWKFromKey(c.getPublicKey()),
    { name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", hash: "SHA-256" },
    true,
    ["verify"]
  ); // Gets RSAKey first, then transforms into a JWK, then imported to get CryptoKey
  console.log(
      await crypto.subtle.verify(
        jsRsaAssignKey.algorithm.name,
        jsRsaAssignKey,
        byteArrays.signature,
        byteArrays.body
      )
  )
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Note: Please do not suggest a NodeJS library. The environment I need to run the script in doesn't support Node core modules.

Comment: I am not a JavaScript developer. I am not sure what you are trying to do here **encoder.encode(jwt.signature),**. The JWT signature is base-64 encoded. Therefore I think you need to base64 decode the signature before calling **crypto.subtle.verify**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `crypto.subtle.verify(algo, key, signature, data)` parameters,

1. the `signature` supplied to the function should be a TypedArray (Uint8Array) of the **URL-base64 decoded** version of raw signature string supplied in the JWT. It should *not* be the TypedArray of the raw signature string.
2. the `data` supplied to the function should be a TypedArray of the string of `<header>.<payload>` **as supplied** in the raw JWT string. It should *not* be the decoded, parsed, and then stringified header and payload that looks like `{"typ": "JWT"}.{"iss": "https://issuer.com/"}`

It must also be noted that the JS built-in `TextEncoder` by default will not be returning the correct `Uint8Array`. Instead of using it to transform the string into a TypedArray, use the `strToUint8Array` function given below.

```
function strToUint8Array(value: string): Uint8Array {
  return Uint8Array.from(
    Array.from(value).map((letter) => letter.charCodeAt(0))
  );
}
```

Thanks to [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for part of the answer on signature decoding.

Answer (score 0):

> // Note the following works
>
> console.log(await jose.jwtVerify('<....JWT string here......>', joseKey))

Then you might as well use that, `jose` is a universal module that works outside of Node.js.

Nevetheless, your manual verify inputs are wrong. `data` should just the jwt without the second dot and signature, encoded as base64url expressed as an ArrayBufferView. `signature` should be the JWT signature part decoded from base64url expressed as ArrayBufferView.